# How to report named properties in JSON format from a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have graph in which nodes are linked to other nodes containing properties. For instance:

```
(:Person {Name: 'A'}) -[:OWNS]-> (:Object {Name: 'Car', Value: 2})
(:Person {Name: 'A'}) -[:OWNS]-> (:Object {Name: 'Computer', Value: 1})
```

Is it possible (how) to report tagged data from a cypher query. Expected format would preferably be:

```
{Person: 'A', owns: {Car: 2, Computer: 1}}
```

My current query is:

```
match (p:Person) -[:OWNS]-> (o:Object) 
return {Person: p.Name, owns: collect({name: o.Name, value: o.Value})
```

this returns

```
{Person: 'A', owns: [{name: 'Car', value: 2}, {name: 'Computer', value: 1}]}
```

Unfortunately, I can't write something like:

```
return {Person: p.Name, owns: collect({o.Name: o.Value})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a person can have any number of cars and computers (including 0):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(car:Object { Name: 'Car' })
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:OWNS]->(comp:Object { Name: 'Computer' })
RETURN { Person: p.Name, owns: { Cars: COLLECT(car.Value), Computers: COLLECT(comp.Value)}} AS result;
```

Here is a sample result for 2 cars and 0 computers for person `A`:

```
{Person:"A", owns:{"Cars":[2,3],"Computers":[]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I was not clear in my question. What I'd like to do is use o.Name to generate "Car": and "Computers": in the output, so that it works regardless the number of properties. If the report was a table, I'd be actually willing to pivot the data.

Comment: A similar question would be "how to set node properties while loading from a tall skinny csv file containing three columns: node identifier, property name and property value"

Answer (score 0):

1: Fetch all nodes: -  `START n=node (*) RETURN n;   or   match (n) return n`

2: Displays the nodes and the relationships: -   `MATCH (n) MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN n,r`   Or   `START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m`

3: Match nodes and relationships: - `MATCH (a:Policy)-[:APPLIES_TO]-(Cluster) WHERE a.name = "pol-1nils" RETURN a, Cluster`

4: Get all object of particular nodes: - `MATCH (list:Policy) return list`

5: bound to the entities between two nodes: - `match (a:WorkLoad)-[b:APPLIES_TO]->(c:Policy) where c.name = "shamshad" return a,b,c;`